# Apply multiple conditional logic to unique account instances

Tags: python, pandas

Been searching around on StackExchange (to no avail) for a method that (1) applies a two-statement, conditional logic (b) each time to a set of unique accounts. For example, I am working with the following test data:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'account':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                    'tot_chg':[2072,2072,2072,322,322,322],
                    'billed':[2072,2072,2072,322,322,322],
                    'denied':[1878,1036,1036,322,161,161],
                    'denied_sum':[1878,2914,3950,322,483,644]})
```

Which produces the following output:

```
    account  tot_chg  billed    denied  denied_sum
0   a           2072    2072    1878    1878
1   a           2072    2072    1036    2914
2   a           2072    2072    1036    3950
3   b            322     322     322     322
4   b            322     322     161     483
5   b            322     322     161     644
```

Note that `denied_sum` is a cumulative sum of the `denied` column for each `account`.

So for each `account` (i.e. 'a' and then 'b', etc.) I would like the conditional statement to return either: (1) the maximum `denied` amount when the `denied_sum` exceeds the `tot_chg` amount, or (2) the `denied` amount if the `denied_sum` equals the `tot_chg` exactly.

I have tried:

```
test['new'] = np.where(test['denied_sum'] == test['tot_chg'], test['denied_sum'],\
         np.where(test['denied_sum'] > test['tot_chg'], max(test['denied']),0))
```

Which yields:

```
    account    tot_chg  billed  denied  denied_sum  new
0   a           2072    2072    1878    1878          0
1   a           2072    2072    1036    2914       1878
2   a           2072    2072    1036    3950       1878
3   b            322     322     322     322        322
4   b            322     322     161     483       1878
5   b            322     322     161     644       1878
```

Close, but I would like to see:

```
    account    tot_chg  billed  denied  denied_sum  new
0   a           2072    2072    1878    1878       1878
1   a           2072    2072    1036    2914          0
2   a           2072    2072    1036    3950          0
3   b            322     322     322     322        322
4   b            322     322     161     483          0
5   b            322     322     161     644          0
```

Something tells me I may need to define a function first, and use it in conjunction with a groupby and apply function, but I'm not quite sure how to bring all the pieces together. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `df.loc` or `df.where`.

Here's a solution with `.loc`

```
test['new'] = test.denied_sum.to_numpy()
test.loc[test.denied_sum.gt(test.tot_chg), 'new'] = 0 # or use `.ge(` inestead of gt for "greater than or equal"
```

`df.where(cond, other)` keeps the current values where condition is true and replaces with *other* (scalar, array, or callable) where it is false.

```
test['new'] = test.denied_sum.to_numpy()
test.new.where(test.denied_sum.le(test.tot_chg), other=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Did not test, if you catch a bug please let me know

Comment: Richie, thank you! Works great. I actually learned a few things just in your one answer here. As sort of a follow-up to this question, is it possible to incorporate multiple conditions into this one where function? Say, test.denied_sum.gt(test.tot_chg) first, and if true, provide test.denied_sum, but if that's not true, then continue to test.denied_sum.le(test.tot_chg), etc.

Comment: You can definitely create a boolean mask that is composed by combining different conditions as in `mask = (cond1 & cond2) | alternative_cond1`, but your new example seems a bit off: `if sum.gt(tot_chg): sum; elif sum.le(tot_chg): ???`

Comment: No, that's fair, I was just making up a random example... Boolean mask, Ok! I'm going to go learn about those now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @RichieV I thought you might enjoy answering this somewhat related question, as it involves the same sample dataset with 2 additional conditions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296347/create-new-column-with-various-conditional-logic-between-other-columns